# How to include dinput.h [C++]

Tags: c++

I'm trying to include dinput.h, however, CodeBlocks isn't able to find it. I searched online and people have been going all over the place on how to find the solution.

`#include <dinput.h>`

Is there an easier way to include that header?

Here's the build message:

`fatal error: dinput.h: No such file or directory`

Comment: Do you know if you even have `dinput.h` on your system?  I have never heard of that particular header.

Comment: dinput.dll is a DirectC DLL, which handles DirectInput http://www.processlibrary.com/en/directory/files/dinput/21979/

Comment: What functionality is requiring the `dinput.h` file?

Comment: Here is your file `http://www.filewatcher.com/p/mingw32-directx-20020518.tbz.53577/mingw32/include/dinput.h.html` Download it and store it into the bin directory of the codeblocks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can find the file in your local file system then include it by:

```
    #include "Path to file/dinput.h"
```

On windows replace / with \ using quotes will enable a search in the file system where as using:

```
   < >
```

Uses the environment variables.

Answer (score -1):

Nevermind. I found the header file here:

ftp://ftp.physik.hu-berlin.de/pub/useful/dx7asdk/DXF/include/dinput.h

Works like a charm.

Just have to make a new file and include the header file like this:

`include "dinput.h"`

Comment: How do you know that's the correct version of the header?

Comment: I'm testing it out by outputting key codes. And it works for me. Maybe it might work for other people.